# Regex: find out if the symbol is surrounded with equal symbols

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a JS regex that will find matches of a word character that are not surrounded by any equal word characters. For example, if we are looking for *b* it should match *aba* or *ubu* and should not *abc* or *bca*.

Any characters in the given string are lowercase English letters, which are alternate (e.g. we can have *ababa* but cannot *bbaa*).

I tried using lookarounds like this:

```
/b(?=a)/g
```

But I did not manage to figure out how do I replace the *a* so that we know that it is the same symbol that is on the left and the right side of `b`. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself, do you want to match `aba` or `abc`? Do you mean literary `b` or any character?

Comment: what about *ababa* in there you have 2x aba + 1x bab wich matches do you want? Because they intersect, but RegEx-matches don't. You need to be more precise with your spec what you want. What are you tryin to build? *Edit:* And what about *bbb*? here you also have a character surrounded by two similar characters, only they're both the same character; middle and surrounding.

Comment: @MarZab Sorry if I was not clear but I do not see any contradictions in the above. It should match literary b. It should match aba (because there is an "a" on the left and "a" on the right of "b") but should not match "abc" because there is an "a" on the left and "c" on the right

Comment: @Thomas in "aba" the match should be "b", in "bab" — nothing if I am looking for "b" and "a" if I am looking for "a". The letters are alternate and there will not be anything like "bbb"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using below regex:

```
(.)(b)(?=\1)
```

You are able to match these kind of characters. If you need to manipulate surrounded `b`s then you can code it like this:

```
> "aabb aba".replace(/(.)(b)(?=\1)/g, function(match, p1, p2) {
    return p1 + 'c';
});
```

```
< "aabb aca"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might do as follows;

```js
var found = "abaubuiyiatbzsgegestsabn".match(/(\w)[^\1]\1/g);
console.log(found);
```

Then if you would like to get all interlaced patterns such is in `"abaubuiyiatbzsgegestsabn"` you should not only get `"geg"` but also `"ege"`

```js
var str = "abaubuiyiatbzsgegestsabn".split(/(\w)(?=[^\1]\1)/g)
                                    .slice(1)
                                    .reduce((p,c,i,a) => i&1 ? (p[p.length-1] += (a.slice(i)
                                                                                   .join("")
                                                                                   .slice(0,2)),p) : p.concat([[c]]) ,[]);
console.log(str);
```